# PHP For Loop, Matching Outputs With Database Results

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, mysqli

I feel like I'm missing something easy here and getting a little stuck while building a "schedule an appointment" calendar.

Clients can book their own time slots, and when they do...I need to make those time slots unavailable to others.

I am using a drop down to "for loop" in 30 minute intervals from 9am - 7pm for the "start time" selection. If a "start time" of "10:00am" and an "end time" of "11:30am" are saved in the database...10:00am, 10:30am, and 11:00am need to be withheld from the "start time" dropdown after successful form submission.

(Database results are in the form of a string...fyi)

To do that, I have this:

```
$sql_slots = "SELECT * FROM XXXXXXXXX WHERE date = '$query_date' ORDER BY XXXXXXXXX ASC";   

    $result_slots = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_slots);  

    $open = strtotime("9:00am");

    echo'
    <select name="start_time">';

        for($b = 0; $b <= 20; $b++){

            $y = strtotime(($b*30) . " Minutes", $open);

            $the_time = date("h:ia", $y) . "<br>";

            $starting = array();

            while($row_result_slots = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_slots)){   

                $starting[] = $row_result_slots['start_time'];

                }

            if(in_array($the_time, $starting)){
            echo "<option>Not Available</option>";
            } else {
            echo "<option>" . $the_time . "</option>";
            }

}
        echo'</select>';
```

Any suggestions, to finish this or a better method than "in_array" to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why is the `while` part in the `for` part? `mysqli_fetch_assoc` will give nothing after the first iteration of the `for`.

Comment: Good call. I moved the while loop to before the for loop and that solved one problem. The other problem was - I was not accounting for the "<br/>" attached to the $the_time string when making the comparison. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to move the "while loop" outside of the "for loop" and I wasn't taking into account the "br" attached to the end of the $the_time variable.

Here is the working code:

```
$sql_slots = "SELECT * FROM XXXXXX WHERE date = '$query_date' ORDER BY XXXXXXX ASC";    

    $result_slots = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_slots);  

    $open = strtotime("9:00am");

    $starting = array();

            while($row_result_slots = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_slots)){   

                $starting[] = $row_result_slots['start_time'];

                }

    echo'
    <select name="start_time">';

        for($b = 0; $b <= 20; $b++){

            $y = strtotime(($b*30) . " Minutes", $open);

            $the_time = date("h:ia", $y);

            if(in_array($the_time, $starting)){
            echo "<option>Not Available<br></option>";
            } else {
            echo "<option>" . $the_time . "<br></option>";
            }
        }
```

Comment: "br" can attached to "echo".echo "<option>" . $the_time . "<br /></option>";